# PHP script cannot be exit() in CLI mode

Tags: php

I have a crontab script which was executed by run-parts every 10 minutes

```
sudo -u www php -f /path/to/parser.php crawl_content1 >> /tmp/job_1.log 2>&1 &
sudo -u www php -f /path/to/parser.php crawl_content2 >> /tmp/job_2.log 2>&1 &
```

my parser.php contians following code

```
$max_execute_time = time() + 9*60;
while(true)
{
   //... do something ...
   if(time() >= $max_execute_time)
   {
       echo "time out!";
       exit;
   }
}
```

my question is **exit** part.
after exit, the script still runing as 10% of CPU and 25% of memory (512MB).
After I changed exit to break, problem solved.

Is there anyone know what's the problem about this?
Thanks

Comment: I've never seen exit without () but maybe it should work anyway

Comment: Since exit is a language construct, the parenthesis is optional unless you pass the status integer.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for this. Are you certain this is what is happening? `exit;` will terminate the process immediately (after executing any shutdown functions and outstanding `__destruct()` functions) and release all consumed resources back to the system. Are you 100% certain you are looking at the right process?

Comment: @Daniel It should be noted that parenthesis are not optional for every language construct (notably `isset()`, `empty()` and `list()` all require them)

Comment: Have you tried *passing* an exit status; specifically, a non-zero exit status (since something failed, execution time exceeded)? `exit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a tangential response, but I find it odd that you implemented your own max execution timer, when PHP has *at least three ways of doing it for you* (saving you the trouble and CPU cycles of calculating it yourself in the script):

```sh
sudo -u www php -d max_execution_time=30s -f /path/to/parser.php crawl_content1 >> /tmp/job_1.log 2>&1 &
```

Or, at the top of your script:

```php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
```

Or (equivalent):

```php
set_time_limit(30);
```

(You can also modify `php.ini`, but you understandably probably don't want to.)

I only suggest this because your implementation terminates your *whole script*; there are other instances in which the execution time of a loop might be legitimately limited without terminating the script.